# Selenium hub and docker node

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-grid

Using docker-compose or simple docker run, I am able to spin-up selenium grid and nodes in the same machine and is working fine.
Docker compose file:

```
    hub:
      image: selenium/hub
      ports:
        - "4444:4444"
    firefox:
      image: selenium/node-firefox
      links:
        - hub
    chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome
      links:
        - hub
```

I'm facing problem when I tried to run a chrome docker container and attach that to a hub (Hub is lying on another Linux machine - Jenkins master)

Is it something possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. You probably need to use the V2 Compose format and use the overlay network driver, which will work across hosts.

Comment: Thank you, Would you mind share some online resource if any, that discuss  this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to publish the ports for the instances too and set the hub's address correctly:

```
chrome:
  [...]
  ports:
    - "5555:5555"
  environment:
     - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=1.2.3.4
     - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
```